# How can I ignore delimiters that are escaped when importing a text file in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a text file that is delimited by |, using "fread" in R. But some of the string contain an escaped version of the delimiter. For example:

12341|bank|234225

135543|single\|office|25343452

7897|office|80909

25223|bank|9870

I want the observation in second row, second column to read as "single|office".

Keeping | is not crucial. If I can ignore \|'s entirely, or replace it with another character (eg. "/"), I'm fine with that too. i.e. "singleoffice" or "single/office" are fine.

I need to do this without using shell commands (no "sed").

What would be the fastest way to do this in a big text file (~20GB)? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What happens when you read in the data? Does R identify the escaped delimiters as delimiters and create the preceding value as a new row?

Comment: I get this error: 
"Expecting 36 cols, but line 471 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep='|' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread."

Answer (score 3):

Here are two different possibilities to try:

**1) re-read** Try this to see if the size of the file allows this.  It reads in the file using `readLines`, removes the \| characters and re-reads it:

```
read.table(text = gsub("\\|", "", readLines("myfile.dat"), fixed = TRUE), sep = "|")
```

**2) sqldf**  This does the processing in an sqlite database offloading R.  It reads the data into an sqlite table named `file`, removes the indicated characters using `replace` in the inner select.  Moving outwards the next select splits each line into the first field and everything thereafter and the outer select splits everything thereafter into the remaining two fields and casts the relevant fields to numeric. Finally it is read into R.  Except for the last step where it is read into R occurs outside of R so R's limitations won't apply.

```
library(sqldf)

read.csv.sql("myfile.dat", header = FALSE, sql = 
     "select cast(V1 as numeric) V1, 
            substr( V2, 1, instr(V2, '|') - 1) V2,
            cast(substr( V2, instr(V2, '|') + 1) as numeric) V3
      from (select substr( V1, 1, instr( V1, '|' ) - 1) V1,
               substr( V1, instr(V1, '|') + 1) V2
            from (select replace(V1, '\\|', '') V1 from file))")
```

**3) sqldf - 2**  This one reads in the data using sqldf replacing the delimiter in SQL to avoid doing it in R and then reads it into R.  Then it writes it out to a file and reads it back in again.   The ? should be replaced with any character that does not appear in the file.  If space is at a premium you may wish to uncomment the `rm()`.

```
library(sqldf)

dat <- read.csv.sql("myfile.dat", sep = "?", header = FALSE, 
          sql = "select replace(V1, '\\|', '') V1 from file")
write.table(dat, file = "myfile2.dat", sep = "?", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
# rm(dat)
read.table("myfile2.dat", sep = "|", skip = 1)
```

**Note:** (1) Here are some self contained reproducible runs of the above:

```
Lines <- "12341|bank|234225
135543|single\\|office|25343452
7897|office|80909
25223|bank|9870"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "myfile.dat")

read.table(text = gsub("\\|", "", readLines("myfile.dat"), fixed = TRUE), sep = "|")
```

giving:

```
      V1           V2       V3
1  12341         bank   234225
2 135543 singleoffice 25343452
3   7897       office    80909
4  25223         bank     9870
```

(2) and

```
Lines <- "12341|bank|234225
135543|single\\|office|25343452
7897|office|80909
25223|bank|9870"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "myfile.dat")

library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("myfile.dat", header = FALSE, sql = 
     "select cast(V1 as numeric) V1, 
            substr( V2, 1, instr(V2, '|') - 1) V2,
            cast(substr( V2, instr(V2, '|') + 1) as numeric) V3
      from (select substr( V1, 1, instr( V1, '|' ) - 1) V1,
               substr( V1, instr(V1, '|') + 1) V2
            from (select replace(V1, '\\|', '') V1 from file))")
```

giving:

```
      V1           V2       V3
1  12341         bank   234225
2 135543 singleoffice 25343452
3   7897       office    80909
4  25223         bank     9870
```

(3) and

```
Lines <- "12341|bank|234225
135543|single\\|office|25343452
7897|office|80909
25223|bank|9870"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "myfile.dat")

library(sqldf)

dat <- read.csv.sql("myfile.dat", sep = "?", header = FALSE, 
        sql = "select replace(V1, '\\|', '') V1 from file")
write.table(dat, file = "myfile2.dat", sep = "?", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
# rm(dat)
read.table("myfile2.dat", sep = "|", skip = 1)
```

giving:

```
      V1           V2       V3
1  12341         bank   234225
2 135543 singleoffice 25343452
3   7897       office    80909
4  25223         bank     9870
```

Comment: How could I modify the code if I don't know which column might contain the escaped delimiter? In the actual data, I have 36 columns and any one of them can contain \|.

Comment: The code above (both 1 and 2) replaces it in all columns but if you have 36 columns then you are better to stick with (1) since expanding (2) to that would be awkward.

Comment: I think the file size is too large for (1). It won't finish running.